# Linux: prevent VNC from swapping like mad

Tags: linux, vnc, ramdisk

**EDIT** actually I'm not sure that it's swapping like mad: I've done more testing and it looks like there may some interference causing the noise that may be correlating with network usage.  This is driving me mad :)

I'm accessing a MacMini (with MacOS X 10.4) from my Linux machine using VNC
and there's an issue that is driving me crazy...

My Linux machine has 4 GB of ram and I run a lot of various apps on it and
I've got no issue at all.  It's all snappy and don't hear the hard disk
swapping/read/writing too often.

Now with VNC, the hard disk is swapping like mad... When I'm moving things
on the OS X desktop.

So I was thinking of creating a ramdisk and forcing the temp VNC files to
go into that ramdisk but the problem is I can't find any temp files.

I've attempted to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ true ]
do
    lsof | grep vnc
done
```

And eyeball parse the output to try to find some temp file: no luck.

The VNC version I'm using is this one:

```
 $ vncviewer -version

VNC Viewer Free Edition 4.1.1 for X - built Jan 30 2009 19:33:16
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
```

No matter how much data is coming from the Mac, there should be
plenty of memory (4 GB of ram) so there's really no reason to swap like crazy.  This is driving me *mad*.

Any help as to how I could solve this problem is most welcome because this is literally driving me nuts.

Comment: you could also try iotop to monitor the actual disk i/o to get a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think it's swapping?  Are you sure it's not simply something accessing the hard disk?  Have you checked the swap and memory usage (`free -m`)?